# How to use a property from gradle.properties inside android activity?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How to use a property from gradle.properties inside android activity? Whenever I build the code it throws error. Is there a particular way that the properties can be accessed inside the activities?

Comment: Which property you want to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **can't access** the `gradle.properties` from your Activity.

The `gradle.properties` is used while you are **building** the app, it doesn't exist in **runtime** or inside your apk.

However you can set some values inside the `BuildConfig` class from your `build.gradle` script (reading from the gradle.properties for example).

Just use somenthing like:

```
buildConfigField "boolean", "MY_FLAG", "true"
buildConfigField "String" , "MY_KEY" ,  "\"XXXXX-XXXXX-XXX\""
```

Answer (score 9):

in gradle.properties:

```
SIMPLE_STRING=ABC
```

in build.gradle:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'PREPROD', 'true'
            buildConfigField "String" , "MY_KEY" ,  SIMPLE_STRING
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: It is works for global or sub-module `gradle.properties` I've tried it. But, if you use `custom_name.properties` you must instantiate a `Properties` object to get the file, see here for details: https://android.jlelse.eu/add-version-properties-file-to-your-android-project-8c7982552b1b

Answer (score 5):

you can use `buildConfigField`
for example:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "USED_TOOLS", "\"${android.getBuildToolsVersion()}\""
    }
}
```

will add field `USED_TOOLS` to your application `BuildConfig.java`

```
public static final String USED_TOOLS = "22.0.1";
```

Answer (score 0):

`gradle.properties:`

```
MY_URL="https://www.....com/api/"
```

and in `build.gradle` call it like this:

```
buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"${properties["MY_URL"]}\"")
```