# How to get library dependency version used in Gradle file from android Programmatically?

Tags: android, gradle, retrofit, build.gradle

I'm currently stuck at one Problem regarding Gradle dependancy. I'm implementing application where I need to use various Third-party libraries to get work done & they are working great but currently situation is that I need their version numbers used in Gradle file.

I've found this question most closely related to my problem [Is there a way to list all gradle dependencies programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36536561/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-gradle-dependencies-programmatically) 

But its printing dependency tree using Gradle task using Gradle console so, is there anyway we can get this using Android code?

Also I would like to explain my question in simpler terms , How can I get retrofit2 library version Programmatically ?
[image]

Comment: I hope this will be useful for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925101/how-to-use-a-property-from-gradle-properties-inside-android-activity